# Password protection via .htaccess file: works on one server; denies access without asking for password on another

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-authentication

I need to use an .htaccess file to password-protect all URLs on my site whose querystring contains "fn=ass". For example, this URL should be protected:

http://www.example.com/?foo=123&fn=ass&bar=456

I have this working on my Win7 development workstation (running XAMPP 1.8.4 with Apache 2.4.10).

However, I tried the exact same .htaccess directives on my Ubuntu 14.04 VPS at Media Temple (running Apache 2.4.7), and it's not working correctly.

I can see that Apache is matching on the correct URLs, so that part is working - but the browser doesn't prompt me for a password. I just get a 401 Unauthorized error when I try to load these URLs. The Apache error says:

"This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required."

Here's my complete .htaccess file (lightly redacted). (Ignore the WordPress stuff; the relevant part is the <IfModule>.)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

##
# Password-protect assessment result URLs
##

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    # First, set an environment variable to true if the current URL is a request
    # for an assessment results page.

    # We can't use SetEnvIf for this, because it can't examine the querystring.

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} fn=ass
    RewriteRule .* - [E=require_auth:true]

    # Configure HTTP-Auth

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Password Required"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/example.com/mysite.htpasswd

    # Satisfy the request if the "callcenter" user is logged in, OR if
    # require_auth is untrue

    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Satisfy any
        Require user callcenter
        Allow from env=!require_auth

</IfModule>
```

Things I've already tried / checked / ruled out:

- The file /var/www/vhosts/example.com/mysite.htpasswd does exist, is readable, and does contains an entry for a user named callcenter. However, this doesn't seem to make a difference - if I change this path a file that doesn't exist, or even comment out the AuthUserFile line entirely, the behavior remains the same.
- The .conf file for this vhost does grant "AllowOverride All" to the site's webroot directory.
- I've tried restarting Apache (which shouldn't be necessary for an .htaccess file - but I tried it).
- Changing "Require user callcenter" to "Require valid-user" doesn't help.

Any ideas? It's odd that it works in XAMPP, but not on the Media Temple server.

Earlier, I had *the entire site* password-protected, and that worked fine - although that was done in the .conf file, not the .htaccess, and was a simpler case (just a few lines tucked inside of a <Directory> directive, with no conditionals). (Those lines are currently commented out of the .conf file, so they should not be interfering with what I'm trying to do in the .htaccess file.)